# CSS Defined Background Image Not appearing on some pages

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and I define my background image in the css.

Here is my CSS Code.

```
body 
{ 
    background-image: url('../background_image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

This is applied to all of my pages.
It works on all desktop pages, but on mobile, it only works on the index page.
I link the pages to the css file using the following at the bottom of the head

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">
```

All of the page files can reference the image correctly since everything works on desktop.
I have heard about a bug in the android system, but since it works on the index page on mobile, i don't think that this is it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guessing it is either another CSS overwriting the rule or the path is wrong. Best to use `/full/path/to/img.jpg`.

Comment: already tried that. Same result. And that is the only place in all of my css where i reference the body

Comment: When you open your developer tool, and select the body element, and type background-image, what value set do you see? I think that there is another css that is overriding your background-image like what Cody Fulford suggested. Here is what I mean https://ibb.co/bxO5SG

Comment: Does `<body>` of other pages (not index page) have any content? Or are you sure it has height greater than 0?

Comment: @orabis, I do not know how to inspect the elements on a mobile device.
It works fine on desktop so i don't think checking there is going to help me.

@C

Comment: Could you provide a mock screenshot so I can apply the required accordingly?

Comment: @orabis, screenshot of the code or the display?

Comment: When you reduce the width of your browser, while not on mobile device, are you able to reproduce the same issue?

Comment: Tried and the background appeared correctly

Comment: After removing everything inside the body, I was able to see the background image. By slowly adding things back in I was able to determine that the background image is being pushed down even though its position is fixed. This does not happen on desktop.

Comment: Can you post a JS fiddle or codepen example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the background image was being "pushed down" the page on mobile.

In my css, I had `background-position: center;` which centers the image on the page horizontally, but the top position was variable.

Changing this to `background-position: center top;` allowed me to see the background image on mobile.

I eventually changed it to `background-position: center -200px;` to get the desired positioning.

Thank you to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format:

`background-image: url('http://example.com/folder/background_image.jpg');`